# Using RTK Query Hooks To Prefetch Data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit, react-navigation-bottom-tab

In a react native project, I use Bottom Tab Navigation from React Navigation.

Within the file that initializes the navigation stack, I directly invoke a RTK query hook without using any of its returned value like data, isLoading, isUnitialized etc. Reason for this is so I can prefetch data needed in 2 unmounted screens, Events & Favorites, see code below.

```
// MainNavigator.tsx
export default function MainNavigator() {
  // Pre-Fetch Events
  useGetLatestEventsQuery();

  return (
    <Tabs.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Tickets"
      tabBar={(props) => (
        <BottomTabBar
        />
      )}

    {/* Events */}
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="Events"
        component={EventsNavigator}
      />

     {/* Tickets */}
     <Tabs.Screen name="Tickets" component={TicketsNavigator} />

    {/* Favorites */}
    <Tabs.Screen name="Favorites" component={FavoritesNavigator} />

...
```

In the Tickets Screen, I use the correct hook for fetching tickets as it is going to be the first screen on the navigation so there's no need to fetch the tickets data ahead of time. So, on both the Events & Favorites screen, I basically then use the `useGetLatestEventsQuery` hook again but I skip the query at first so I can then use the refetch method from it to force the query again on refresh of the screen.

```
export default function Events() {
  const events = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.event.events);

  const [skipQuery, setSkipQuery] = useState(true);
  const { isFetching, refetch, isUninitialized } = useGetLatestEventsQuery(
    undefined,
    { skip: skipQuery }
  );

  const handleRefresh = () => {
    isUninitialized ? setSkipQuery(true) : refetch();
  };

  return (
    <Layout
      refreshing={isFetching}
      onRefresh={handleRefresh}
      emptyScreen={events?.length === 0}
      loading={events === null || isFetching}
    >
      <EventsCarousel events={events ?? []} />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Is this approach considered anti-pattern?

Comment: I don't think there's all-purpose design patterns: you explained well what you wanted to achieve but not WHY. Tell us more why you didn't go for the standard use: did you want to improve display time, have you some other problems with using the hook in both screen? Does the hook shares the cache correctly so the query is sent only once to the server?

Comment: @BenjaminCaure Apologies if the WHY wasn't implied. The purpose is to readily have the events data available on navigation to either the Events or Favorites screen. The `useGetLatestEventsQuery` hook dispatches an action that updates the event state in the store upon its completion. I then simply then tap in to the store to use the events state in the Events & Favorites screen hence the {skip:true} in those screens at first.

Comment: Ok so I understand it's kind of display time improvement: did you look at redux toolkit prefetch?  https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/prefetching#recipe-prefetch-immediately

Comment: @BenjaminCaure Thanks, it works for my use-case. Is there any difference perfomance-wise between my initial approach of simply invoking useGetLatestEvent() and using usePrefetch("eventsEndpoint") which returns a function that I then use in a useEffect?

Comment: I think it the same in term of performance, it just makes more sense to use the standard way, in my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in comment, your goal is to reduce display time for tab components.
So your solution is not anti-pattern, but it's not very self-explanatory.
You can use [Redux Toolkit Prefetch](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/prefetching#recipe-prefetch-immediately) which achieve the same goal than you solution, and will be simpler for other developer to understand.